# Exception raised during rendering: Circular dependencies cannot exist

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

Was editing the GUI from activity_main.xml in Android Studio and suddenly I got the formentioned error. I'm not familiar with XML at all(I'm just the designer of the app), any help would be appreciated to get this up and running again so I can continue on with the design.

```
<TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="162dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@drawable/imagebutton1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="243dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView2" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:background="@drawable/imagebutton2"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_gravity="center|left"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="68dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Partly Cloudy"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:textColor="#D1DBBD"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton2" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="22 ºC"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:textColor="#D1DBBD"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:background="@drawable/line"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Bradford"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textColor="#193441" />
```

Comment: check your relative placements of the UI elements. If you are saying something like "let element X be below element Y" and also a condition "let element Y be below element X", then circular dependencies are created. so, comb thro' the xml file and chart out on a paper where lies what in relation to each element and in relation to the screen edges. Also, avoid using id values such as "@+id/textView". Give meaningful names like "@+id/login_textview", etc. helps ease of reading and conflicts in naming.

Answer (score 1):

A circular dependency is when a resource A depends on a resource B, but resource B also depends on A. Something like `A -> B -> A`, making a 'circle'.

In your case the resources are Views, and I can see at least one circular dependency: your `textView2` depends on `textView3` (`android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"`) which by itself depends on `textView2` (`android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView2"`). When this happens it's not possible for the system to properly align them.

Try to arrange your layout in another way to avoid this case. Use `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout`to group several views if that makes it easier.